# Script/macro that searches if the lookup value pair (in column's D,E) exists in lookup array (in column's A,B)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

Script/macro that searches if the lookup value pair (in column's C,D) exists in lookup array (in column's A,B).

I came across `MATCH` `VLOOKUP` but they look up only one value but what I want is something as follows.

Please note :  COLUMN A  is always in sorted order

```
  A          B         C              D         E         F
 _______________________________________________________________________
  BOB        100      details1       CCA       100        print "False"       
  BOB        200      details2       DBA       100        print "False"         
  BOB        300      details3       BOB       100        print "details1"         
  CCA        500      details4       BOB       500        print "False"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an array formula in `F1`

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> together

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$4,MATCH(D1&E1,$A$1:$A$4&$B$1:$B$4,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are comparing Column D&E and with Column A&B respectively and when both the respectivecolumns match, you are printing Column 3 value in Column 6 against the matched set of values.

```
Sub macro()
Dim a, x, y As Integer
a = 1
Cells(a, 4).Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    x = ActiveCell.Value
    y = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Cells(1, 1).Activate
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        If ActiveCell.Value = x Then
            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = y Then
                Cells(a, 6) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            End If
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
    a = a + 1
    Cells(a, 4).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!